# Django - Render a List of File Names to Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, twisted

I am generating a template for an image gallery page.  My approach is as follows:

- Host the images from a sub directory of an images folder

  - The image folder will be titled the same as the gallery title
- The view passes a list of filenames to the template
- The template loops through the list and creates img tags

So my view would be

```
def some_gallery(request):
    #LOGIC TO GET A LIST OF FILENAMES

    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'user' : request.user,
        'title' : 'something',
        'files' : fileList
    })
    return render_to_response('gallery_template.html',variables)
```

And the template

```
....
{% for file in files %}
    <img src="/path/to/images/{{ title }}/{{ file }}">
{% endfor %}
....
```

The problem I am running into is that Django is putting up a 500 error when I try to use the os.listdir function.  How can I get the file list that I need??

Problematic version of the view which is giving the 500 error

```
def some_gallery(request):

    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'user' : request.user,
        'title' : 'something',
        'files' : os.listdir('/path/to/gallery')
    })
    return render_to_response('gallery_template.html',variables)
```

Also I should note that the file path does work, so if I go directly to the url, I get just the image as expected.

**EDIT:** Fixed the typos in code samples

Comment: What OS and web server you are using?

Comment: What is the error message that's being thrown?  That will probably say what's going wrong.  `listdir` should work for Windows and Unix-like systems, so there's likely a problem in how you're using it.

Comment: I was going for permission problems and get the error message thru the webserver

Comment: I am using an Twisted Web Server on Ubuntu Server.  As in the comment below, the way I am using listdir works fine in a Python shell, just not in the Django view.  I'm guessing it is permissions within the Twisted server

Comment: Usually a server error appears in the webserver log files, can you find it and post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it sorted out.  My methods were correct, so anyone looking to do this type of thing, the code samples should work.

The problem that I had was that Django was tripping up on the listdir function call due to some problems accessing the file path that was provided.  I made sure the directory permissions and path was correct and it worked.

Thanks to those that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary is not a valid python code because you are using "=" instead of ":". It should be:

```
variables = RequestContext(request,{
    'user' : request.user,
    'title' : 'something',
    'files' : os.listdir('/path/to/gallery')
})
```

One last thing, listdir expects an abosulte path, you can get the root path of your project with:

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8')).replace('\\', '/')
```

Comment: os.listdir() doesn't expect an absolute path. It can be any path as long it is a path to something.

Comment: The "=" was a typo in the post, idk why I did that, lol.  I am using the ":" operator as I should.  Second, if I run a Python shell, the os.listdir is working fine, just not in the Django view